# Convert VLC video stream to bitmap for xzing to decode using C#

Tags: c#

I need to convert a VLC video stream (working) in my WPF app to a bmp for Xzing to be able to decode,
I can decode using a usb or the onboard webcam.

But how to get the 2 together??

Been searching all over and have tried some solutions but nothing seems to work, might be me as i'm pretty new to C#

Thanks

I tried this piece of code:

```
    public static void Get_Frame(Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl vlc)
    {
        try
       {
            if (File.Exists(Temp_Frame_Filename))
            {
                File.Delete(Temp_Frame_Filename);
            }

            vlc.TakeSnapshot(Temp_Frame_Filename, width: (uint)vlc.Size.Width, (uint)vlc.Size.Height);

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Code");
        }
    }
```

I cant get it to work because I don't know how to call it,
I want to call it from a dispatch timer but I get errors.

Sorry for not answering questions correctly, will get the hang of this forum.

Try get the whole function in:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Draw the video box into an image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vlc"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static void Get_Frame(Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl vlc)
    {
        try
       {
            if (File.Exists(Temp_Frame_Filename))
            {
                File.Delete(Temp_Frame_Filename);
            }

            vlc.TakeSnapshot(Temp_Frame_Filename, width: (uint)vlc.Size.Width, (uint)vlc.Size.Height);

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Code");
        }
    }
```

I tried doing this:

```
        void Codetimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        ZXing.BarcodeReader Reader = new ZXing.BarcodeReader();
            Result result = Reader.Decode(Temp_Frame_Filename);
            if (result != null) TxtScannedResult.Text = result.ToString();
        }
```

Get an error cannot convert from string to system.drawingbitmap.

Thanks

I think I went down the wrong path with that attempt,
I somehow need to convert a VLCVideo stream to bitmap for Xzing
any ideas please

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: To be honest I cant even call the function from a dispatch timer

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory - you're passing a string (the file name) as a parameter to the `Reader.Decode` method. There is no overload for that. You need to pass in an image.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little test with Vlc.DotNet.Wpf 3.0.0 and ZXing.Net 0.16.5.
I'm not sure why you are speaking about a WPF app but then you are using the Vlc.DotNet.Forms namespace. I used the Vlc.DotNet.Wpf.VlcControl.
Here is the proof of concept code (perhaps there is a better solution for threading and locking, but it works):

First, I added the VlcControl to my WPF form:

```
<Wpf:VlcControl Name="vlcControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="380" Margin="87,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="367" Loaded="VlcControl_Loaded"/>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
    private int isWorking;
    private System.Threading.Timer decodingTimer;
    private ZXing.IBarcodeReader<BitmapSource> reader = new ZXing.Presentation.BarcodeReader();

    private void VlcControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((VlcControl)sender).SourceProvider.CreatePlayer(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC"));
        ((VlcControl)sender).SourceProvider.MediaPlayer.SetMedia(new FileInfo(@"How Barcodes Work - YouTube.mp4"));
        ((VlcControl)sender).SourceProvider.MediaPlayer.Play();

        decodingTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(DoDecoding, null, 500, 500);
    }

    private void DoDecoding(object state)
    {
        if (Interlocked.Increment(ref isWorking) == 1)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var bitmap = vlcControl.SourceProvider.VideoSource as InteropBitmap;
                    if (bitmap != null)
                    {
                        var result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(result.Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception )
                {
                    // add handling here
                }
                finally
                {
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref isWorking);
                }
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref isWorking);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help, I tried your solution and it works perfectly.
I have implemented in my solution and am getting the following error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any ides why?
Here are some code snippets:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
  private ZXing.IBarcodeReader<BitmapSource> reader = new                ZXing.Presentation.BarcodeReader();
        private System.Threading.Timer decodingTimer;


and

    private void DoDecoding(object state)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    InteropBitmap bitmap = videoSin.SourceProvider.VideoSource as    InteropBitmap;
                    if (bitmap != null)
                    {
                        var result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(result.Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }

             ));

        }
```

The Video stream works and I only get the error when I present a barcode to the camara.
   Thanks

Comment: Please post a full stacktrace from the exception.

Comment: Been trying to figure out how to do that, can get the Call stack but doesn't show much, please explain

Comment: Catch the exception, show it with MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()), copy it from the shown message box with "Strg+C" to the clipboard, paste the contents of the clipboard here in a comment

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at ZXing.Datamatrix.Internal.BitMatrixParser..ctor(BitMatrix bitMatrix) in C:\ZXing.Net\Source\lib\datamatrix\decoder\BitMatrixParser.cs:line 36

   at ZXing.Datamatrix.Internal.Decoder.decode(BitMatrix bits) in C:\ZXing.Net\Source\lib\datamatrix\decoder\Decoder.cs:line 62

Comment: at ZXing.Datamatrix.DataMatrixReader.decode(BinaryBitmap image, IDictionary`2 hints) in C:\ZXing.Net\Source\lib\datamatrix\DataMatrixReader.cs:line 68

   at ZXing.MultiFormatReader.decodeInternal(BinaryBitmap image) in C:\ZXing.Net\Source\lib\MultiFormatReader.cs:line 210

   at ZXing.BarcodeReaderGeneric.Decode(LuminanceSource luminanceSource) in C:\ZXing.Net\Source\lib\BarcodeReaderGeneric.cs:line 223

   at SinicaDatabase.MainWindow.<DoDecoding>b__84_0() in D:\BURNTECH AUTOMATION\Projects\Sinica\Apex Scanners\SinicaDatabase\SinicaDatabaseDB\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 648

Comment: That seems to be the same error which is fixed by the following pull request:
https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/pull/226
For the moment you have to options:
1. restrict the reader that it doesn't try to decode a DataMatrix code:
`private ZXing.IBarcodeReader<BitmapSource> reader = new ZXing.Presentation.BarcodeReader { Options = new DecodingOptions { PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> {BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE} } };`
2. catch the NullReferenceException and don't show it via MessageBox:
`catch (NullReferenceException nex)
{}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox...
}`